# Android inApp purchase with Paytm

Tags: android, in-app-billing, paytm

This is not a technical question but more of clarification on google inApp guidelines:

I want to sell a product via inApp. As per google payment guidelines I can't give external link for payment.

> Payment Processing and Policies
>
> In general, the terms of Google Play
>   allow you to sell in-app subscriptions only through the standard
>   payment processor, Google payments. For purchases of any subscription
>   products, the transaction fee is the same as the transaction fee for
>   application purchases (30%).
>
> Apps published on Google Play that are selling subscriptions must use
>   In-app Billing to handle the transaction and may not provide links to
>   a purchase flow outside of the app and Google Play (such as to a web
>   site).
>   More details can be found at
>
> https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#payment

I have seen Ganna.com is selling subscription via Paytm wallet. Below is the link for incorporating Paytm sdk:

> http://paywithpaytm.com/developer/paytm_sdk_doc?target=how-paytm-sdk-works

My questions are

1. Do we need to pay 30% revenue to google?
2. Is it not vialation of
3. Payment processing and policies of Google?
4. Does Paytm pays to google?
5. How the Paytm revenue sharing works?

Answer (score 1):

> Do we need to pay 30% revenue to google?

No, not when you use Paytm as payment method.

> Is it not violation of Payment processing and policies of Google?

Not really sure. what i know is it depends on what you are offering as "Product" you mentioned. if the product you are selling is in a physical form them you can't use In-App purchase and in that case you can use third party payment integration. take this with pinch of salt, i'm not expert.

> Does Paytm pays to google?

No, they do not.

> How the Paytm revenue sharing works?

AFAIK they have flat 2% cut over each transaction done via your app. You probably have to ready latest documents for exact value though.

Regarding how Ganna does it, that procured me to dig a little bit. i'll post update if i find anything.